# MySQL update query is executed but no change in data for some rows

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Unfortunately there is no error message. This is my update query, and it works granted that it always reaches the `echo` statement after `execute()`. The strange thing is it does not reflect the update on *some* rows (some rows do get updated), even if correct data is being sent on the network payload. Another strange thing is that this totally works in localhost, but not in live server.

```
include_once("../connections/db.inc.php");
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
  try {
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $column = $_POST['column'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET $column = :value WHERE md5(userId) = :id OR userId =:id LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":value", $value);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
      print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    }
    echo "y";
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Currently the `id` is being retrieved using a simple loop

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
$id = md5($row['userId']);
...
```

and the fields are inline editable

```
<td>
 <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="updateValue(this, 'userLevel', '<?php echo $id;?>')">
  <?php echo $userLevel; ?>
 </div>
</td>
```

with a jquery ajax to send data into the php file above

```
function archiveRow(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'archiveusers.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    success: function(php_result) {
      console.log(php_result);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If this pdo or mysqli?

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You can't parameterise column names, but to mitigate that, you absolutely 100% need to whitelist them

Comment: PDO won't throw exceptions unless you tell it to... see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Does the AJAX request contain the expected data? Does PHP handle the request properly? If only **some** update executions are affected: is there a pattern for working / non-working requests?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your code is working, your comparison is flawed:

```sql
WHERE md5(userId) = :id OR userId = :id
```

The `md5`function returns a string and `:id` is `PDO::PARAM_INT`. In MySQL, the comparison of string with number is guaranteed to produce unexpected results:

```
select '912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570' = 912 -- 1
select '912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570' = 913 -- 0
```

Your php code should be like this:

```
$sql = "... WHERE md5(userId) = :id_str OR userId = :id_int";

$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id_str, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id_int, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

That still looks incorrect to me though. The roper solution is to check if `$_POST['id']` contains a md5 hash or an integer (using `filter_input` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP`) then build the query + parameters based on that.

Comment: I removed the ``md5()`` altogether for the ``userId`` and now its fine. the md5 seems very inconsistent, although it does work 100% of the time in localhost

Comment: It might have updated wrong rows 100% of time :)